# removeObjectAtIndex crashing the app

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In the .h file I have set the below line.

```
  NSMutableArray *repArray;
```

In the .m file I have placed the below lines.(I put just the required lines of code for this ex)
-(void)read_data_fromDB
{
    objectsForCharacters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

```
sqlite3 *db = [contactAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];

NSMutableString *query = nil;

query = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"select representative, title, business_name, uid from corporate where profiler_type <> 'OWN_CORPORATE' order by representative asc"];  

const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *selectAllStmt = nil;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql, -1, &selectAllStmt, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0,@"error preparing statement",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
else
{
    repArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    businessArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
uidArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    while(sqlite3_step(selectAllStmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {


        char *chrstr =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 0);
        if(chrstr !=NULL)
        {
            corpRepresentative = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chrstr];
            [repArray addObject:corpRepresentative];
        }       
        chrstr =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 1);
        if(chrstr !=NULL)
        {

            corpTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chrstr];
            [titleArray addObject:corpTitle];
        }
        chrstr =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 2);
        if(chrstr !=NULL)
        {
            corpBusiness_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chrstr];
            [businessArray addObject:corpBusiness_name];

        }   

        chrstr =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectAllStmt, 3);
        if(chrstr !=NULL)
        {
            corporteUid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:chrstr];
            [uidArray addObject:corporteUid];

        }


    }


}
sqlite3_finalize(selectAllStmt);

sqlite3_close(db);
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 

{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture =
    [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)] autorelease];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}

// Configure the cell...

UILabel *txtLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 175, 26)];
//[txtLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[txtLbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
NSString *txtStr = [repArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIFont *fontTxtLbl =  [UIFont fontWithName: @"FuturaMdBT" size:16];
[txtLbl setFont:fontTxtLbl];
[txtLbl setText:txtStr];
[cell.contentView addSubview:txtLbl];
[txtLbl release];


    UILabel *txtDetailLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 27, 175, 20)];
   // [txtDetailLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [txtDetailLbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    NSString *txtDetailStr = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *fontTxtDetailLbl =  [UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size:12];
    [txtDetailLbl setFont:fontTxtDetailLbl];
    [txtDetailLbl setText:txtDetailStr];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtDetailLbl];
    [txtDetailLbl release];


UILabel *txtDetailLbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 47, 175, 20)];
//[txtDetailLbl1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[txtDetailLbl1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
NSString *txtDetailStr1 = [businessArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIFont *fontTxtDetailLbl1 =  [UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size:12];
[txtDetailLbl1 setFont:fontTxtDetailLbl1];
[txtDetailLbl1 setText:txtDetailStr1];
[cell.contentView addSubview:txtDetailLbl1];
[txtDetailLbl1 release];

   // cell.textLabel.text = [repArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];






UIView *viewSelected = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
viewSelected.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:224.0/255.0
                                               green:229.0/255.0
                                                blue:241.0/255.0
                                               alpha:1.0];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = viewSelected;

cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 
                                                    green:77.0/255.0 
                                                     blue:141.0/255.0 
                                                    alpha:1.0];


return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{



    NSString *tempUID = [uidArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:tempUCID forKey:@"corpUcid"];


    [prefs setObject:@"PROFILER" forKey:@"selProfiler"];

    CorpPrevFront *corpPrevFront = [[CorpPrevFront alloc]initWithNibName:@"CorpPrevFront" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:corpPrevFront animated:NO];
    [corpPrevFront release];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];



}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    //FOR VIEW
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && [alertView tag] == 1) {
        // IT WILL BE MATCH ON CorpPrevFront CLASS

    }
     //FOR DELETE
    if(buttonIndex == 2 && [alertView tag] == 1){



    } else if(buttonIndex == 1 && [alertView tag] == 2){
        DeleteProfiler *delProfiler = [[DeleteProfiler alloc]init];

        BOOL del = [delProfiler deleteProfiler:selectedCpUid];
         //[delProfiler deleteProfiler:selectedCpUcid];
        if (del == YES) {


          [repArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.section];
            [businessArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
            [titleArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
            [ucidArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];



        [self.corporateTable reloadData];



                   }


    }
}
```

I am trying to delete an array element from a method. If I execute the below line then the app crashes automatically in my iPod Touch. But it works fine in simulator without any errors.

```
[repArray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
```

or

```
[repArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

both crashes the app even if I have more than one elements in array.

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: @Philippe Sabourin I dont know really how to accept answers for my previous questions.

Comment: @Benj I didnt get any error message. It works fine in simulator without errors. But not in iPod

Comment: @dinesh Looks like you figured it out :) 83% is much better.

Answer (score 1):

When you app crashes like that, 99% of the time you are trying to remove an object beyond the bounds of array.

Comment: Might be, but why I have this problem doesnt exist in the simulator.

Comment: Peter Could you help me on this please?

Comment: I can try - but you need to post more code - where you create the array and more code in context where remove the objects from array. Also, have you checked that the indexPath.row is smaller than the array object count?

Comment: Peter I have uploaded additional code for you. Please have a look. I am sure the problem is in the removeObjectAtIndex.

Comment: Then please upload the code that is actually relevant. The whole function where your app crashes, and the error message displayed by the debugger.